# How to refer a figure as a table?

Tags: tables, graphics, floats

If I have a table from an excel file which I print screened and posted as a figure in LaTeX. However, I want to make it a table. Problem is, the particular table has a lot of values in it so making it into a table manually is pretty tedious.

Is there a way to be able to reference an image as a table instead?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can put `\includegraphics...` into a `table` floating environment:

```
\begin{table}
  \caption{A stunning table}
  \label{tbl:excel-table}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{excel-table}
\end{table}
```

The distinction between `table` and `figure` is a semantic one—separate counters etc., but technically, they work the same.

Comment: Can the opposite be done too? Refer a table as a figure?

Comment: That's what I tried to express with the last sentence.

Comment: I started looking for this on the internet a little tense, because I didn't want to have to rewrite my excel tables in latex. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Use the `\captionof` command (it is included in the `caption` package).

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{./img/some_image.png}
\captionof{table}[foo]{foobar}
\label{img:foobar}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I would not recommend this, because this could disturb caption styling, hyperlinks etc.

Comment: But this is useful in a minipage, where I cannot use the first solution by Svante of replacing "figure" by "table".

Answer (score 2):

You can save your excel file as .csv file(comma delimited). I found a converter( [a CSV to LaTeX file converter](https://launchpad.net/csv2latex))
It should work.

If you want to plot a graph from excel .csv file. u could follow http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tips_and_Tricks#Graphs_with_gnuplot