# Creating bullets within a subsection

Tags: formatting

I'm fairly new to LaTeX, and I have no idea how to fix this. Basically I make a subsection using `\section`, and then create subsections using `\subsection`. Now I need to create bullets within the subsection, but I can't find syntax that works.

Comment: Do you want your subsection heading to be bulleted? Or do you just want to know how to make a bulleted list? (in the latter case, just use the `{itemize}` environment.)

Comment: I want to make a bulleted list within the subsection, I'll try the itemize

Comment: This is really a super basic question that is covered in any intro to LaTeX.  See [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23381/2693) for some suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

It should work out if you just use the following syntax at the respective place in your document:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item First bullet point 
\item Another bullet point 
\item Add as many bullet points as you want
\end{itemize}
```

That way, it should be working, now matter whether you are writing within a section or a subsection or even a subsubsection. :)