# Refer to a table as figure

Tags: tables, graphics, cross-referencing, captions

I have a table where I have put pictures (plots) in each cell. The whole point of making this table is for comparison of the plots. However it does not look good to refer to this set as a table, because indeed it is just a big figure.

Is there any easy way of referring to this table as figure in text, and also in the caption?

BTW, I checked this question already, [How to refer a figure as a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23381/how-to-refer-a-figure-as-a-table). It is the corollary of my question, but the solution for it does not seem to work in my case.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\label{table:mul}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\toprule

\textbf{A} & \adjustimage{height=8cm,valign=m}{PlotA} \\
\midrule
\textbf{B} & \adjustimage{height=8cm,valign=m}{PlotB} \\
\midrule
\textbf{C} & \adjustimage{height=8cm,valign=m}{PlotC} \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{I don't want a table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\begin{figure}\caption{Not a table}\label{fig:plots}\input{plots}\end{figure}`

Comment: `\captionof{figure}{And now for something completely different}\label{somelabel}` using `caption` package in the `table` environment

Comment: @AndrewCashner I removed the table label and caption, put it in a separate file and tried your solution, I got ``Not in outer par mode'' error.

Comment: Which of the 50000000 different `Thesis.cls` files do you use? ;-) And where is `\begin{document}`?;-) A lot of missing packages and a wrong label ;-)

Comment: @AndrewCashner: I stole your proposition and merged it with my 'way', if you don't mind.

Comment: I just used `\input` to make the comment shorter. Generally I think it's a good practice to keep anything with heavy formatting like tabulars in separate files. In my comment above, the input file would just contain `\begin{tabular}`... `\end{tabular}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both Andrew Cashner's and my proposition should work, the images are listed in the `LoF`, not as table and referenced as figures as well.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside,demo]{Thesis}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\listoffigures


%%% Andrew Cashner's way

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\toprule

\textbf{A} & \adjustimage{height=8cm,valign=m}{PlotA} \\
\midrule
\textbf{B} & \adjustimage{height=8cm,valign=m}{PlotB} \\
\midrule
\textbf{C} & \adjustimage{height=8cm,valign=m}{PlotC} \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{I don't want a table: Andrew Cashner's way} \label{faketable:mul}

\end{figure}


\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\toprule

\textbf{A} & \adjustimage{height=8cm,valign=m}{PlotA} \\
\midrule
\textbf{B} & \adjustimage{height=8cm,valign=m}{PlotB} \\
\midrule
\textbf{C} & \adjustimage{height=8cm,valign=m}{PlotC} \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\captionof{figure}{I don't want a table: My way} \label{table:mul}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One would have to weigh the advantages of either environment. For instance, if you've used `etoolbox` to set up uniform formatting like `AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\singlespacing}` and this "tabular figure" needs that formatting, then it makes sense to use `table` with `\captionof`. Otherwise, if it's a figure I would just call it a figure.